# Iterating over JSON parent sections, testing for action and then returning payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

given this json structure:

```
{
  users: [ { action: 'add', payload: [Array] } ],
  categories: [ { action: 'add', payload: [Array] } ],
  products: [ { action: 'add', payload: [Array] } ]
}
```

How would you use `.map()` or `Object.keys` or similar ES6 goodness to iterate through each node (users, categories, products), and then get the "add" action (so i can if/then to different operations) and also the contents of the payload array for each section?"

Comment: That isn't JSON

Comment: To all OPs: The right way to say "JSON" is:  "Given the following pixels painted by your browser, representing a javascript literal that may or may not have been previously serialized as JSON, <insert your question here>".  It takes a little extra effort, but hopefully you'll avoid irritating anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just interested in the values, you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
const data = {
  users: [ { action: 'add', payload: [Array] } ],
  categories: [ { action: 'add', payload: [Array] } ],
  products: [ { action: 'add', payload: [Array] } ]
};

Object.values(data).forEach(([{ action, payload}]) => // do anything with them);
```

If you need the keys as well, try [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, [{ action, payload}]]) => // same );
```

Comment: Much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Don't mention it!